# How to write a Prolog predicate to split a list into a list of paired elements?

Tags: recursion, prolog

This was a question on a sample exam I did.

Give the definition of a Prolog predicate split_into_pairs that takes as arguments a list and returns as a result a list which consists of paired elements. For example, `split_into_pairs([1,2,3,4,5,6],X)` would return as a result `X=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`. Similarly, `split_into_pairs([a,2,3,4,a,a,a,a],X)` would return as result `X=[[a,2],[3,4],[a,a],[a,a]]` while `split_into_pairs([1,2,3],X)` would return `No`.

It's not meant to be done using built-in predicates I believe, but it shouldn't need to be too complicated either as it was only worth 8/120 marks.

I'm not sure what it should do for a list of two elements, so I guess that would either be not specified so that it returns no, or `split_into_pairs([A,B],[[A,B]])`.

My main issue is how to do the recursive call properly, without having extra brackets, not ending up as something like `X=[[A,B],[[C,D],[[E,F]]]]`?.

My most recent attempts have been variations of the code below, but obviously this is incorrect.

```
split_into_pairs([A,B],[A,B])
split_into_pairs([A,B|T], X) :- split_into_pairs(T, XX), X is [A,B|XX]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a relatively straightforward recursion:

```
split_into_pairs([], []).
split_into_pairs([First, Second | Tail], [[First, Second] | Rest]) :-
    split_into_pairs(Tail, Rest).
```

The first rule says that an empty list is already split into pairs; the second requires that the source list has at least two items, pairs them up, and inserts the result of pairing up the tail list behind them.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/1ZZ7Dr).

Your solution [could be fixed as well](http://ideone.com/ezF0z4) by adding square brackets in the result, and moving the second part of the rule into the header, like this:

```
split_into_pairs([A,B],[[A,B]]).
split_into_pairs([A,B|T], [[A,B]|XX]) :- split_into_pairs(T, XX).
```

Note that this solution does not consider an empty list a list of pairs, so `split_into_pairs([], X)` would fail.

Comment: Ok so it looks like I actually did have this as one of my attempts, but as I misunderstood how the Tail works, I didn't think it was correct. Thank you for your help, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is *almost* correct. It has obvious syntax issues, and several substantive issues:

`split_into_pairs([A,B], [` **`[`** `A,B` **`]`** `] )`**`:- !.`**

`split_into_pairs([A,B|T], X) :- split_into_pairs(T, XX),`

`X` **`=`** `[` **`[`** `A,B` **`]`** `| XX ]` **`.`**

Now it is correct: `=` is used instead of `is` (which is normally used with *arithmetic* operations), both clauses are properly terminated by dots, and the first one has a cut added into it, to make the predicate deterministic, to produce only one result. The correct structure is produced by enclosing each pair of elements into a list of their own, with brackets.

This is inefficient though, because it describes a ***recursive process*** - it constructs the result ***on the way back*** from the base case.

The efficient definition works ***on the way forward*** from the starting case:

```
split_into_pairs([A,B],[[A,B]]):- !.
split_into_pairs([A,B|T], X) :- X = [[A,B]|XX], split_into_pairs(T, XX).
```

This is the essence of *tail recursion modulo cons* optimization technique, which turns recursive processes into ***iterative*** ones - such that are able to run in constant stack space. It is very similar to the *tail-recursion with accumulator* technique.

The cut had to be introduced because the two clauses are not mutually exclusive: a term unifying with `[A,B]` could also be unifiable with `[A,B|T]`, in case `T=[]`. We can get rid of the cut by making the two clauses to be mutually-exclusive:

```
split_into_pairs([], [] ).
split_into_pairs([A,B|T], [[A,B]|XX]):- split_into_pairs(T, XX).
```