# How to make a predicate that will make a list of pairs?

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

I want to make a predicate `pairlist(X,Y)` in Prolog that when it is given a list 
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6], it will make pairs in the list `Y = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`. Can you please help me? Basically, I can't understand how will I divide the list in pairs..
Thank you

Comment: Please show what you've tried and ask a more specific question. See the [stackoverflow.com onliine help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for information about asking good questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a Prolog predicate to split a list into a list of paired elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112260/how-to-write-a-prolog-predicate-to-split-a-list-into-a-list-of-paired-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a very simple solution:

```
pairlist([],[]).
pairlist([A],[[A]]).
pairlist([A,B|T],[HL|TL]):-
    HL = [A,B],
    pairlist(T,TL).
```

Comment: You don't need `HL = [A,B]`. Just write, `pairlist([A,B|T], [[A,B]|TL]) :- pairlist(T, TL).` Also, the OP didn't indicate whether it should succeed or fail for a list with an odd number of elements. So it's unclear whether `pairlist([A], [A]).` is desired. This is another case of an OP not offering much information and wanting someone to do all of their work for them.